# MAMP Pro (Mac OS) Php Versions

Tags: php, mamp-pro

I'm currently evaluating MAMP Pro. Have started developing a new site using PHP 8.0.8 (latest available version). I've tried to update a component using Composer and It's whingeing that I need to be running PHP 8.1. Cam I able to add this to MAMP or do I need to wait for an update?